# How do you set ViewerPreferences with jsPdf

Tags: jspdf

The default seems to be fit to windows width and enable scrolling, I would like to set it to : fit one full page to windows.

I was looking everywhere on the [official documentation](http://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/global.html) but I could find a clue.

Answer (score 1):

```
var doc = new jsPDF()
doc.text('This is a test', 10, 10)
doc.viewerPreferences({'FitWindow': true}, true)
doc.save("viewerPreferences.pdf")

// Example printing 10 copies, using cropbox, and hiding UI.
doc.viewerPreferences({
  'HideWindowUI': true,
  'PrintArea': 'CropBox',
  'NumCopies': 10
})
```

[Check Document](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/global.html#viewerPreferences)